# Exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder

Tags: android

I am developing Android Application and After published it on play store, I facing this problem many time.

```
Exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected.Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{2f9d83c position=11 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent}
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition (RecyclerView.java:5297)
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:5479)
android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline (GapWorker.java:282)
android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline (GapWorker.java:336)
android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline (GapWorker.java:349)
android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch (GapWorker.java:356)
android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run (GapWorker.java:387)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:815)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:104)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5737)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:789)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

I searched for long time about this problem and applying many Solution but the Exception still raised

One of Solution that I applied was Making Custom LinearLayoutManager:

```
public class WrapContentLinearLayoutManager  extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    //... constructor
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        try {
            super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
            setAutoMeasureEnabled(false);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e("Error", "IndexOutOfBoundsException in RecyclerView happens");
        }
    }

    public WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
        setAutoMeasureEnabled(false);
    }

    public WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        setAutoMeasureEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In My Application depends on RecyclerView with **Load more** and **Swipe to Refresh** features

I using Volley to get Data from web Service for **Load more** and **Swipe to Refresh**

To Load More Item in RecyclerView, inside the call back of Volley Response I append the new Items in to ArrayList and notify the adapter Like this:

```
    final int positionStart = list.size() - 1;
    final int itemCount = response.length();
    for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++)
    {
        try 
        {
            obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
            list.add(new ItemEntry(obj.getInt("Id"),obj.getString("Title").trim()obj.getBoolean("isFavorite"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(index == 0)
        { 
            // for first Initialize for adapter 
            adapter = new MyAdapter(latestEntryList,getActivity());
            adapter.setOnItemClickCallBack(mainFragment);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else
        {
            // for load more items
            recyclerView.post(new Runnable() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                   adapter.updateItems(positionStart,itemCount);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The Code for Adapter.UpdateItems

```
  public void updateItems(int positionStart,int itemCount) {
        itemsCount = getItemCount();
        this.notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart,itemCount);
    }
```

In case of load More I do the following; in OnRefresh

```
   public void onRefresh() {
        listFragment.LatestEntry(0,false);
// 0 the index and False isAppend to list of not
    }
```

The code for LatestEntry is:

```
   private void LatestEntry(final int index, final boolean isAppend)
        {
        String customerId = "123";
        String uri = String.format(BASE_URL+"/api/Entry/LatestEntry?customerId=%s&index=%s",customerId,index);

            JsonArrayRequest LatestEntryJsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, uri,
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) 
                   {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                        if(response.length() > 0 && !isAppend) 
                        {
                            int startPosition = 0;
                            int preSize;

                            if(adapter != null)
                                preSize = adapter.entries.size();
                            else
                                preSize = 0;
                            if(preSize > 0 && EntryList.size() > 0) {
                                EntryList.clear();
                                adapter.entries.clear();
                                adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(startPosition, preSize);
                            }
                        }

                        final int positionStart = EntryList.size() - 1;
                        final int itemCount = response.length();
                        for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++)
                        {
                            try {
                                obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                list.add(new ItemEntry
                               (obj.getInt("Id"),obj.getString("Title").trim()
                                  obj.getBoolean("isFavorite"));

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        if(index == 0) 
                        { // for first Initialize for adapter 
                            adapter = new MyAdapter(latestEntryList,getActivity());
                            adapter.setOnItemClickCallBack(mainFragment);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // for load more items
                            recyclerView.post(new Runnable() 
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                   adapter.updateItems(positionStart,itemCount);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    setListShownNoAnimation(true);
                    if(mainFragment.swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
                      mainFragment.swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
            );

            LatestEntryJsonArrayRequest.setTag("LatestEntry");
            KidsSingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(LatestEntryJsonArrayRequest);
        }
```

Please note the Following:

1. The Recyclerview Version is: recyclerview-v7:25.3.0
2. I have Three RecylerView in ViewPager
3. Each ViewPager Contain Fragment and The Fragment Contain ListFragment  with RecylerView.
4. There are one Adapter for all RecylcrViews.

Can any one help to overcome this issue?

Comment: What is the version of your reccyleview support library ?

Comment: I use this version recyclerview-v7:25.3.0

Comment: FYI: `onLayoutChildren()` is not a problem here - your stacktrace doesn't show it in the list.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem here. Looks like a `prefetch` feature bug. These errors only appear after Google added this feature on 25.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I have similiar situation - viewpagers as items of recycler view. While adding\removing items there was some animation for these "waiting to be removed" items. So when I was calling remove item, and animation still was acting I've got:

```
IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling
```

To avoid this exception I've created a handler to delay removing items. BUT! This is wrong. If you've changed data of adapter RV should be immediately without any handler or multithreading notified about these changes. 
So, think about changing this way into something where updates won't need separate threads.

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition` complains about not receiving a valid `ViewHolder` item, while it seems to be at the offset position of the 11th item.

would assume you might have forgotten to inflate the `ViewHolder` when adding more items to the Adapter... the way of processing appears wrongful; while ordinary, one only has to update the data array and then notify the Adapter with eg. `notifyDataChanged()`; think when adding items directly to the Adapter, these notifications are being triggered internally.

the `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)` probably should happen within a callback method, so that the wheel animation disappears, when the loading has completed.

maybe check this [example](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) to get an idea in which order the framework triggers the events (hence it is often the problem, that one creates functionality, which the framework already brings with it)... stepping into might also provide a clue, why there is no valid `ViewHolder` being inflated for that item.

Comment: I tried you suggestion, and now on **Loading more** I adding data to temp list then updates adapter's list one time and then called `notifyItemRangeInserted`, but after I published the app to Google Play the exception appeared again.

Comment: @MohammedK.Abuhalib can only guess, while not having seen the crash reporting; chances are good that ProGuard obfuscates a little too much (and probably even has `-dontnote` or `-dontwarn` flags for that class, therefore not complaining about unknown classes)... removing (or commenting out) these configuration rules would be the first step I'd take. uploading the `mapping.txt` is also useful.

Comment: I don't use ProGuard obfuscates, I don't use `-dontnote` or `-dontwarn` flags and also proguard-rules.pro file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the list that you set to adapter has been changed but the notifyDataSetChanged has not been called.
In my case, I delay the call for notifyDataSetChanged. But the getItemCount() for the adapter has changed to another value, so it crashs.

Answer (score -1):

Call `notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart,itemCount)`

Before calling `notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart,itemCount);`

Worked for me.